# AWS Managed Apache Airflow Dags Log Search

Tags: airflow, amazon-emr

AWS Managed Apache Airflow Dags Log Search, Airflow jobs runs as step in EMR cluster.
We are facing issue in looking the failed Dags log. Output shows only S3 folder.

EMR job failed for reason Unknown Error. with message None and log file s3://test-bucket-logs/j-HNKNG13GHYTD/steps/s-UYHJGTHEFGER/ INFO marking task as FAILED. dag_id=test_tag, taks_id=test

We have to go to steps/s- folder then fetch the application log ID then again go to container folder to see the logs.

Is there any solution for this??/